# Insert clock into a program

Tags: c, linux

I want to ask if there is any way by which I can open a file to read after every 30 seconds.  Like, I want to insert a clock in which I call a file open function after every 30 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Sjoerd's answer, here is a possibility:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define FREQ 30
void sig_handler(int signum) {
    // do whatever you want every FREQ seconds

    //reenable the timer
    alarm(FREQ) ;
}

int main() {
    signal(sig_handler, SIGALRM) ;

    //enable the timer
    alarm(FREQ) ;

    while(1) {
        //do whatever you want between signals
    } 
}
```

it seems to work in my quick test

Comment: if there is a lot of work to be done every 30 seconds, you probably don't want this to happen in the sig_handler itself.  Then the sig_handler() should set a flag, and you could test for that flag in the while()-loop.  But then you will run in to a whole lot of other trouble.  I suppose "Advanced UNIX programming" cover this in great detail.  http://basepath.com/aup/

Answer (score 2):

You can periodically run code using [alarm()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm).

Comment: could u please tell me how to use alarm() or what it does thanks

Comment: be careful with signal handlers : your program can be interrupted anytime. it could be interrupted in the midle of a computation or a memory write operation. Your data is most likely inconsistent when executing the signal handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your program does within the 30 seconds. But if you just want to do a short operation with your file and the wait until the next 30 seconds, then you could just run these operations in a loop and sleep for 30 seconds:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

   while( true ) {
      FILE* myFile = fopen( "foo.txt", "r" );
      // do whatever you like with your file.
      fclose( myFile );

      // sleep for 30 seconds and then open the file again.
      sleep( 30 );
   }
}
```

If you want to do a lot of other computation during these 30 seconds you should consider multithreaing but that's another topic ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There isn't any reason as to why it can not be done. Its not just opening files, you can do whatever you want after a certain interval. There are several ways to implement it, even by using services provided by linux.

You may like to add a bit more detail as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: You didn't answer the question, so this isn't an answer. If you want to ask for more information, please add a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: i have ha file in which data will be updated after every 30 sec.i want to ask is there any built in function like which i gave an interval and it will call the file updation function after every 30 sec thanks